# Diving through a complex data structure, a HasMap

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a HashMap which looks like :

```
( student1 => Map( name => Tim,         
                   Scores => Map( math => 10,
                                  physics => 20,
                                  Computers => 30),
                    place => Miami,
                    ranking => Array(2,8,1,13),
                  ),
  student2 => Map ( 
                   ...............
                   ...............
                ),
   ............................
   ............................
);
```

Since the keys are not any particular type(objects, Strings, Integers etc), how can I "dive" through this complex HashMap ?

EDIT:  "dive" means to iterate through each and every keys and values.

Comment: what is meant by dive through?

Comment: As I've already told you in your previous post, submit your requirement and you can get better help with your design, you're like asking the community how can we do your work step by step.

Comment: Is this a materially different question to the one you posted an hour ago: [How do I dump the contents of a HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007860/how-do-i-dump-the-contents-of-a-hash-map)?

Comment: @GregKopff there is [Creating complex HashMap in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11008083/1065197) question too. It's really bad when a person prefer to ask for fish instead of learning how to go fishing by himself.

Comment: If your keys are not of a particular type, your model might need a redesign. On the other hand, all keys are subclasses of `Object`. The `Map` interface specifies `Object` as type for the `get` and `contains` operations, so no problem there. But the real question is: Why are you using such an unwieldy data structure to start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
Map<Long, Student> studentIdToStudentMap = new HashMap<Long, Student>();
```

and

```
class Student{
  private String name;
  private List<Score> scores;
  private Location location;
  private List<Rank> rankings;
  //const, equals(), hashcode(), accessors
}
```

and

```
class Score{
   private String subject;
   private float marksObtained;
   private float totalMark;
   private Long examId;
   //const, equals(), hashcode(), accessors
}
```

Like wise

Comment: Yes, thats good. But "students" is just an example of what I actually requires and that cannot be transformed into a class. So I need the Data structure.

Comment: You can take this as an example to create class for your model

Answer (score 1):

Totally untested and not guaranteed to be fit for any purpose (your question is somewhat vague), but it should give you the idea on how to work with your problem:

```
public void doStuffWithMap(Map yourMap)
{
  for(Map.Entry entry : yourMap.entrySet())
  {
    if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map)
      doStuffWithMap((Map)entry.getValue());
    else
      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use something like

```
private static printKeyValues(Map map) {
  for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
    if(map.get(key) instanceOf Map) {
      printKeyValues((Map)map.get(key))
    } else {
      System.out.println("key:" + key+" value:"+ map.get(key));
    }
  }
}
```